# VirtualQueryEx error - too many pages

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, paging

I'm using VirtualQueryEx to enumerate a module's memory pages with the following code:

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)module;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
    unsigned long usage = 0;
    for ( ;VirtualQueryEx(hProcess, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize ) 
    {
        printf("%#10.10x (%6uK)\t", info.BaseAddress, info.RegionSize/1024);

        switch (info.State) {
        case MEM_COMMIT:
            printf("Committed");
            break;
        case MEM_RESERVE:
            printf("Reserved");
            break;
        case MEM_FREE:
            printf("Free");
            break;
        }
        printf("\t");
        switch (info.Type) {
        case MEM_IMAGE:
            printf("Code Module");
            break;
        case MEM_MAPPED:
            printf("Mapped     ");
            break;
        case MEM_PRIVATE:
            printf("Private    ");
        }
        printf("\t");

        if ((info.State == MEM_COMMIT) && (info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE))
            usage +=info.RegionSize;

        int guard = 0, nocache = 0;

        if ( info.AllocationProtect & PAGE_NOCACHE)
            nocache = 1;
        if ( info.AllocationProtect & PAGE_GUARD )
            guard = 1;

        info.AllocationProtect &= ~(PAGE_GUARD | PAGE_NOCACHE);

        switch (info.AllocationProtect) {
        case PAGE_READONLY:
            printf("Read Only");
            break;
        case PAGE_READWRITE:
            printf("Read/Write");
            break;
        case PAGE_WRITECOPY:
            printf("Copy on Write");
            break;
        case PAGE_EXECUTE:
            printf("Execute only");
            break;
        case PAGE_EXECUTE_READ:
            printf("Execute/Read");
            break;
        case PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE:
            printf("Execute/Read/Write");
            break;
        case PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY:
            printf("COW Executable");
            break;
        }

        if (guard)
            printf("\tguard page");
        if (nocache)
            printf("\tnon-cachable");
        printf("\n");
    }
```

The code was taken from another post here.

The problem is: VirtualQueryEx won't stop enumerating pages at the current module (it just stops when memory is out of process) and the results are **wrong**

Here's my output and VMMap's one

[image]

As you can see starting from the address highlighted the pages are all wrong and VirtualQueryEx won't even stop enumerating them.

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: You cannot safely use VirtualQueryEx() on a running process, it may well allocate or release pages while you are iterating it.  Which produces this kind of mishap.  It is a debugger function, debuggers freeze all the threads in a process first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMMap knows about [pe](/questions/tagged/pe) file format (sections .data, .text, ext), VirtualQueryEx don't. MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.RegionSize -  the size of the region in which all pages have identical protection attributes (RW in screenshot). That is why mismatch in calculating regions VMMap and VirtualQueryEx.

[image]

VirtualQueryEx won't even stop enumerating them.

```
p += info.RegionSize
```

scans the entire user mode virtual memory address space. If you want to stop the scanning, check the AllocationBase field.